# Undefined array key "carts"/Laravel10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I defined 1-n relationship between Model/User.php and Model/Cart.php.The first one is Model/User.php; the second is the function checkoutPost in Controller.

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $guards = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'email_verified_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function carts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class,'users_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkoutPost(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $message = [ 
            'required' => ':attribute không được bỏ trống',
            'min' => ':attribute phải lớn hơn 4 kí tự', // this is my message but in different language, dont worry about it
        ];

        $data = $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required|min:3',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'phone'=>'required|min:9',
            'address'=>'required',
            'payment_method'=>'required',
        ], $message);

        $data = $request->only('first_name','last_name','email','phone','address','payment_method');
        $data['users_id'] = $user->id;

        $order = Order::create($data);

        $user->carts->each(function ($cart) use ($order) {
            OrderDetail::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id,   
                'product_id' => $cart->product_id,  
                'price' => $cart->price,    
                'quantity' => $cart->quantity
            ]);
            $cart->delete(); 
        });                             
    
        return redirect()->route('order.checkout');      
    }
}
```

It cause the error in this line `$user->carts->each(function ($cart) use ($order)`

I'm doing the Checkout process in my E-commerce project. The codes seem correct to me, but I keep getting that error message. Also, I do have cart data exists in the database.

Comment: The error message "Undefined array key 'carts'" indicates that the carts relationship is not loaded on the $user model instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that error trying to access that property it sounds like you are not using Eloquent at all. You are most likely using an authentication guard that is using a User Provider that is using the `database` driver, not the `eloquent` driver, which returns a `GenericUser` object which is not an Eloquent model.

Eloquent will give you a `null` for a non-existing attribute/relationship/property. The `GenericUser` has a `__get` method that is directly trying to access an array called `attributes`, which if the key doesn't exist will throw such an error.

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->attributes[$key];
}
```